# Handling errors in a Tape test?

Tags: node.js, testing, tap, node.js-tape

If I have a function that throws an error and I want to test for that error, I'd write something like this:

```
test('throws at something that is not a string', t => {
  t.plan(1)
  t.err(loadString(9))
})
```

But this always results in an actual error coming from the function while executing:

[image]

And there's the `not ok 1 no plan found` and `not ok 2 no assertions found`, which is also weird. How can I make sure it doesn't actually throw?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to test if the function will throw, you have to use `t.throws` and pass it a function (not the error value). Here, I assume `loadString` is the actual function you are testing, so YOU are actually causing it to throw instead of Tape invoking it and catching the error.

Try this instead:

```
t.throws(function() { loadString(9); });
```